# google calendar API repeat timezones

Tags: php, laravel, google-calendar-api, recurring

Im trying to insert a repeat event using this wrapper:
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar

Having noproblems with dates, but date+time involves timezones

I keep getting this error:

**(400) Missing time zone definition for start time.**

```
[
          "name" => "Test name here"
          "location" => "Brisbane Australia"
          "description" => "Desc here..."
          "timeZone" => "Australia/Brisbane"
          "colorId" => 4
          "startDateTime" => "2017-03-01 14:00:00"
          "endDateTime" => "2017-03-01 15:00:00"
          "recurrence" => ["RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;"]
]
```

i dont know how to add timezones to these start and end datetime values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry mate, the package cannot do it.

> **Limitations**
>
> The Google Calendar API provides many options. This package doesn't support all of them. For instance **recurring events cannot be managed properly with this package**. If you stick to creating events with a name and a date you should be fine.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-google-calendar#limitations

Comment: I think the warning is about "managing recurring events". It does says "If you stick to creating events with a name and a date you should be fine."

Comment: Well, he is trying to insert `repeat` event. Is it different from recurring?

Comment: I believe the official name for "repeat event" in Google Calendar is [Recurring Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents). Also, the data he supplied is an event definition with `recurrence` rules, which basically is a recurring event. (Names are confusing ...)

Comment: i have eventually gotten it to work, but im having difficulty with timezones so far

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Calendar API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events), the field `start.dateTime` (supposedly your `"startDateTime"` field) is assumbed to be [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) format. (I assume you have to do the same with `endDateTime`).

You need to covert the date to that format.

If your raw data is a [DateTime object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), you can convert it like this:

```
<?php

$startDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2017-03-01 14:00:00");
echo $startDateTime->format(DateTime::RFC3339);
```

Will output:

```
2017-03-01T14:00:00+08:00
```

Time zone is included in this format.